# monotouch 'Func' delegate?

Tags: c#, xna, system, func, mscorlib

I'm trying to compile some code in MonoTouch but I'm getting an error: 'type or namespace name 'Func' could not be found'

According to MSDN the delegate 'Func' is found in System and specifically the mscorlib assembly, I'm not sure if that is included in MonoTouch?

Not too sure what I should do at this point, I'm thinking maybe I should just replace Func with my own version of it (it doesn't seem to be too complicated as a delegate).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Func is available in MonoTouch according to the documentation: http://go-mono.com/docs/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3aSystem.Func%601

You could easily replicate the declaration of the Func delegate.  Perhaps you could post your usage of it so we can check that?

Comment: It is being used in the Farseer physics library (which I'm attempting to copmile in monodevelop for iOS).

It is being used here:

        private Func<Fixture, bool> _queryAABBCallback;
        private Func<int, bool> _queryAABBCallbackWrapper;

As an example. Also probably related is another error I' getting for system.action saying that System.Action<T> requires '1' type argument(s) here: public event Action<Joint, float> Broke;

Comment: @meds: Matt is right, MT has Func. Depending on the version of MonoTouch, it's either in mscorlib or in System.Core. Check that the project has both references.

Comment: @Jb Evain, yep it looks like he was correct. Looks like I'm dealing with a bug in MonoDevelop or something to do with the compiler, but it's not because of the function missing from the library.

Answer (score 2):

Func (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, TResult) Delegate

is declared like this in mscorlib (found using reflector):

```
namespace System
{
public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, in T3, in T4, in T5, in T6, in T7, in T8, out TResult>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8);
}
```

Declare the same delegate yourself and you'll be able to use it.